# Structure (key, value) with repetition Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, key-value, repeat

Is there a java structure like HashMap but that allows to repeat the key as well as the value ?

For example:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "Sport");
map.put(1, "Football");
map.put(2, "Football");
map.put(1, "Handball");
```

And as a result:

```
<1,"Sport">
<1,"Football">
<2,"Football">
<3,"Handball">
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks, 
Nadhmanovic

Comment: `HashMap<Integer,List<String>>`?

Comment: No, HashMap<String,List<Integer>>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a structure like this built into the language. But you can use Guava's [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap).

Answer (score 2):

would using the

```
Map<Key, List<Value>>
```

help?

Comment: It pretty seems to be the definition of a "multiset" without (in general) keeping the chronological order, nice!

Answer (score 0):

A List holding a object that has a Integer and a String can work for you and will also keep the order added.

But if you want to find all elements with the same key you will need a for, or a structure like `Map<Integer, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MultiMap<Character,Boolean>` because it allows duplicate key which exist in `org.apache.commons.collections` package.

or

You can use `ArrayList` and add the objects of the Class to the same key.

Hope this helps!